# DNS resolution broke after upgrading to 18.04, resolvconf broken or not fully installed

Tags: 18.04, dns, resolv.conf, netplan, resolvconf

when googling i find stuff like this: askubuntu resolvconf

but /etc/resolv.conf doesn't seem to exist

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf

returns that resolvconf is broken or not fully installed

heard 18.04 might be using netplan instead now, but /etc/netplan seems to be completely empty

not sure what to do now, any help would be appreciated

EDIT: running sudo apt install resolvconf asks me to remove openresolv, whatever that is, not sure if i should do that :/

EDIT: /etc/network/interfaces is completely empty aside from loopback interface, can still ping IP addresses tho

Comment: How did you perform this upgrade? - upgrading should not remove resolvconf. - upgrading should not install openresolv, which is an alternative implementation that has never been supported by Ubuntu. - upgrading should install the netplan package but will not remove ifupdown. - upgrading using any supported method does NOT delete configuration from /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: The short answer should be "you don't need resolvconf on 18.04, /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink to systemd-resolved instead".  But it sounds like you have several other things going wrong with your system.

Comment: seems like resolvconf was broken, not sure how or why, but reinstalling it manually seems to have fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone encounters a similar issue, here's how i fixed it

download resolvconf.deb manually from official Ubuntu source: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/resolvconf/resolvconf_1.79ubuntu10_all.deb

transfer to Ubuntu PC using USB

```
sudo apt purge resolvconf
sudo apt install ./resolvconf_1.79ubuntu10_all.deb
sudo dpkg --reconfigure resolvconf
reboot
```

and then it should be fixed