# Ubuntu 20.04 unable to ping domains but can ping IP addresses

Tags: network-manager, dns

Some how I've messed up the DNS after a failed app install! I notice that in /etc/ there are 3 resolv files:
resolv.conf
resolv.conf_bak
resolv.conf-tmp

resolv.conf contains:

```
#Generated by NetworkManager
search lan
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

resolv.conf_bak contains:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8) ...
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search lan
```

resolv.conf-tmp contains:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

`systemctl status systemd-resolved` returns:

```
systemd-resolved.service
Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit systemd-resolved.service is masked)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

In the Wifi network settings (GUI) the IPs 8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1 are listed under IPv4 DNS and IPv4 method is Automatic (DHCP), DNS and Routes are also set to Automatic.

I had installed OpenLiteSpeed webserver which is accessible via localhost:7080 but probably this install has upset domain name resolution and browsing. I don't know enough about Linux DNS to know where else to look for the conflict. Should I try re-installing systemd-resolved as posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075692/dns-resolution-broke-after-upgrading-to-18-04-resolvconf-broken-or-not-fully-in)?

## UPDATE 1:

Following suggestions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207493/unit-systemd-resolved-service-is-masked) I ran `ls -l /etc/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service` and got this reply: *"ls: cannot access '/etc/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service': No such file or directory"*
I then ran `sudo systemctl unmask systemd-resolved` and the reply was "*Removed ...*". I then ran the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved
```

The last one confirmed the creation of a symlink from */etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service* to */lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service* and also one from */etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/systemd-resolved.service* to */lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service*

`sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved` now returns *Unit system-resolved.service could not be found.*

## UPDATE 2:

If I add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolv.conf` then name resolution/browsing is restored, but this file is generated by resolvconf so I assume it will be overwritten!

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/a/604775/1120211) suggests adding the nameserver to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` with `supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;`

Any ideas please?

Comment: First thought….why is systemd-resolved masked? Did the install of OpenLiteSpeed do that? Also, `/etc/resolv.conf` is supposed to be a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`. I suspect this has been changed as well.

Comment: @mpboden thank you for your pointer. So there maybe something wrong with the symlink or it's missing. I've found more info at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207493/unit-systemd-resolved-service-is-masked I will try the resolutions suggested there.

Comment: The last command at the end of your "Update 1" has a typo in it. It should be `systemd-resolved` not `system-resolved`. Please edit question again with the output of `systemctl status systemd-resolved`. Also, add the output of `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`.